# Export specified field of a collection in mongodb / mongodump to file

Tags: mongodb

I want to dump a single specified field to file.
Let's say I have a collection users with name, email and id, but I only want to print out all contents of field url, like this statement in mongod:

```
db.users.find({}, {"email": 1});
```

Now I tried mongodump with the query option, but it doesn't work:

```
mongodump --db 'mydb' --collection 'users' --query '{}, {"email" : 1}'
```

Basically I just want the contents of a field into a readable file. Is there a way to do it on the commandline without a script?

edit:  I found a solution myself. I needed 'mongoexport' which has a fields option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mongodump` will not give you a readable file, it's bson format.  You want mongoexport:

```
mongoexport -d mydb -c users -f email --csv -o outputFile
```

Comment: Thanks! I found it too, additionally I needed "--csv" - without it, you get all the _ids automatically.

Comment: I actually already added it in a quick edit to my answer before you commented on it :)

Comment: Hi Asya, how about mongodump? How can I specified specific fields in mongodump? I use bson files in my Hive via mongo-hadoop so I was wondering whether I can select some fields to reduce the size of the bson. tnx

Comment: since mongodump will dump bson (native format for mongodb) it can only dump entire documents. there is currently no way to output only a subset of fields directly that I'm aware of.