# How to dump single field for Mongo 2.4?

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm trying to dump all values of just one field (`id`) in a particular collection using `mongodump`. I.e. the same as returned by this query:

```
db.my_collection.find({},{id:1})
```

I'm trying

```
mongodump -d my_database -c my_collection -q -q "{},{id:1}"
```

When I do this, it dumps all fields.

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886046/export-specified-field-of-a-collection-in-mongodb-mongodump-to-file) has suggested

```
mongodump -d my_database -c my_collection -f id
```

But it looks like that flag has been removed because

```
ERROR: unknown option -f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK mongodump does not support projection. You can use mongoexport:

```
mongoexport -d my_database -c my_collection --fields id
```

Comment: Won't that just find the record with `id = 1`? That's not what I want.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. If you edit your answer to include only the second bit I will accept it.